# Is faceless rudraksha powerful than all faced ones?

Tags: rudraksha

I currently have Panchamukhi Rudraksha. Is nirakara (faceless) Rudraksha more powerful than all faced ones? According to 
http://www.shivamrudraksha.com/face-less-rudraksha-with-om-mark.php

Comment: This question is not about Yoga, Tantra etc.. Only Rudraksha is the correct tag. You may remove the other tags you added.

Comment: @Rickross Well, you could have done that in your edit since you also have editing privileges?

Comment: @Aoi.T_015 please don't decide these things without proper consultation. Wearing wrong kind of Rudraksha may not be good. 5 mukhi is normally good for everyone. Sadhguru says Ekmukhi should not be worn by householders. So take care. https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/wisdom/article/the-significance-of-rudraksh

Comment: And also refer this FAQ https://www.ishashoppe.com/in/the-rudraksha-guide

Answer (score 4):

Different Mukhi beads ranging from zero to twenty-one faces are also occasionally available. Each Mukhi is used for a different purpose, and better being aware of all their different qualities. Wearing the wrong type could disturb one’s life.

> Answer to your question in simple words each has its own power but to
>   be consider power full ***The Eighteen Mukhi Rudraksha*** is a rare
>   one and is ***the most powerful bead*** for prosperity. This is our Mother
>   Earth' Rudraksha. Wearing her bead, you will acquire immense wealth.

### All Rudraksha Information provided below:

> **According to [rudrakshanepal.com](http://www.rudrakshanepal.com/rudraksha-beads/rare-rudraksha/nirakar-rudraksha/?activate_redirect=0)**
>
> > The **faceless rudraksha(nirakara)** - the one without line - round and perfect with a natural hole befits its name of Nirankar Rudraksha.
> >
> > The wearer feels complete and whole and the wearers charisma increases day by day making people more receptive and acceptive to the wearer naturally.
> >     Nirankar Rudaksha works on improving personal confidence and self-worth, removes any resistance, anger, insecurities one has with people thus improving relationships on all levels. Improves and structures thought patterns so that one has clear, structured positive thinking.
> >
> > Removes any worries from the mind on wealth and relationships. Beneficial for stock-traders, lawyers, bankers, teachers or in those in professions where confidence, charisma, stability and long term business or people to people relationship is required

### The One Mukhi Rudraksha

Symbolizes Lord Shiva. This is the supreme Rudraksha for anyone who want to get connected to the Supreme power. It destroys all sins and allows you to liberate yourself. On a physical point of view, this kind of bead cures migraines and diseases from the brain.

### The Two Mukhi Rudraksha

Represents the combination of Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati. It blesses the wearer with harmony and unity. This type of Rudraksha cure emotional weaknesses. It helps to wearer to release fear and find inner happiness.

### The Three Mukhi Rudraksha

Frees the wearer from his past birth Karma, releasing past memories of anger, and any kind of feeling associated to low self estime. It allows you to shine and reveal your truth.

### Four Mukhi Rudraksha

Associated to Lord Brahma, the creator of the Universe and the representation of knowledge and creativity. Wearing this Rudraksha your power of concentration, of knowledge and creativty will increase.

### Five Mukhi Rudraksha

Are the most common type of Rudraksha. It is safe and good for everyone – man, woman and child (up to 12 years old). This is the Rudraksha type we mostly use. The 5 Mukhi Rudraksha is used for general wellbeing, health and freedom. It enhance awareness, destroying the bad karma of the present life and helps those who whish to discover their higher-selves.

### Six Mukhi Rudraksha

Makes the wearer more connected to Motrher Earth. It gives you stability and increases your stability and grounded feeling.

### Seven Mukhi Rudraksha

Represents the Goddess of wealth, Goddess Mahalaxmi. It promotes good physical health, wealth and abundance.

### Eight Mukhi Rudraksha

Is associated to Goddess Ganesha, the remover of obstacles. It will help you to gain confidence and achieve success easily, leading to a happier life.

### Nine Mukhi Rudraksha

Is the representation of Goddess Durga, the female form of the Supreme Being. It will protect you from all sufferings and remove your misery. It is the symbol of freedom, freedom from fear, in order to live a life of success.

### Ten Mukhi Rudraksha

Is known to be the most powerful Rudraksha, being able to pacify all the nine planets. It is a strong protector against negative energies and Evil.

### Eleven Mukhi Rudraksha

Is associatied to Lord Hanuman who represents courage, bravery and adventure. It gives the wearer courage and fearless power.

### Twelve Mukhi Rudraksha

Represents our Lord Sun. It allows you to shine, to be radiant and powerful. It helps you to release all tensions, as stress, doubt, worry. It blesses you, give you self-confidence and motivation in your life.

### Thirteen Mukhi Rudraksha

Is a very rare piece that gives the wearer wealth, a divine charisma and an immense power. Helping you to lead a happy and satisfactory life.

### Fourteen Mukhi Rudraksha (or Dev Mani)

Is one of the most precious Rudraksha. It is said that it has came directly from the eyes of Lord Shiva, who was wearing this bead. It activates your Third Eye Chakra, giving you the ability to visualize things clearly and stimulating your spiritual capacities.

### Fifteen Mukhi Rudraksha

Is known to heal the Heart Chakra. Any discomfort related to the heart will disappear.

### Sixteen Mukhi Rudraksha

Protects you and releases all kind of fear and insecurity. It liberates you from the fear of death and cures diseases. It is a strong protector against negative energies. It will allow you to rise in victory and grace.

### Seventeen Mukhi Rudraksha

Allows the wearer to live with great power and divine magnetism. It is associated to Vishakarma, the builder of the Universe. The wearer of this kind of Rudraksha bead, is filled with abundance.

### Eighteen Mukhi Rudraksha

Is a rare one and is the most powerful bead for prosperity. This is our Mother Earth’ Rudraksha. Wearing her bead, you will acquire immense wealth.

### Nineteen Mukhi Rudraksha

Creates satisfaction within you. This bead will help you to attract all what you want, in business, in love and in life in general

### Twenty Mukhi Rudraksha

Is ruled by Lord Brahma, the creator of the Universe. This Rudraksha bead stimulates the knowledge and intellect of its wearer. It gives you strong power and fulfilment of desires.

### Twenty one Mukhi Rudraksha

Is the rarest Rudraksha bead, allowing the wearer to be blessed in all points of view. It is a very strong protector.

### Gauri Shankar

Two beads that have grown and joined together naturally symbolize the holy union of Lord Shiva and Goddess Parvati represented by the Soul and the Mind. The Gauri Shankar Rudraksha is rarely found and blesses the wearer with the gifts of awakening of Inner consciousness, spiritual evolution and oneness with people and elements. It evokes pure universal love. It is known to improve relationships, bring joy and harmony. The Gauri is an extremely influential and powerful Rudraksha that is recommended for meditation.

*There is news recently that a 27 mukhi rudraksha have found in indonesia and nepal.*

> you can go through [rudraksha-ratna.com](https://www.rudraksha-ratna.com/articles/rudraksha-properties) also where each rudraksha is explained well with images to understand.
>   And also got through "[aumrudraksha.com](https://www.aumrudraksha.com/blogs/aumrudraksha/understand-more-about-rudraksha-the-different-mukhi-and-their-meaning)"

*And also I am collecting all new data on rudraksha that are recently found the information is very hard to find*

Comment: Some content appears copied from [this site](https://www.aumrudraksha.com/pages/rudraksha-power). It's ok to copy but you need to put them in blockquotes and leave a link/credit the author/website. See [How to reference material written by others?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @sv. I have Added reference link that I used. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange. It looks like you have copied information from other websites. You didn't put that information in quotes. What you wrote is put in block quotes. You formatted in a reverse way The copied information should be written in block quotes and the website or a source you are copying should be mentioned properly instead of "this website". See [How to reference material written by others](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Also look at [The Copy paste issue - Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/5212)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have edited my answer as described in the link you provided if you fill I am missing something edit or tell me ill do it right away thanks!! :-)

Comment: Oh! You removed information from your answer but that was not needed. It is enough if you give proper attribution for what you have written. Even if it is not copied and you have paraphrased, that is okay. The details about one mukhi Rudraksha, two mukhi rudraksha etc., you have provided were good. The answer was better with that detail. Why did you remove information collected from [aumrudrakha.com](https://www.aumrudraksha.com/blogs/aumrudraksha/understand-more-about-rudraksha-the-different-mukhi-and-their-meaning)? You can quote that website if that can be relied upon.

Comment: ok ill add it again no worry. but the content is good write.

Answer (score 0):

In the **[Devi Bhagwat Puran](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57384.html)** in the section on greatness of Rudraksha beads Shiva Himself narrates to his son Kartikeya the importance of different types of Rudraksha and states:

> O Kārtikeya! **As many faces as there are in the Rudrākṣam, for so many thousand Yugas the holder resides with honour in the Śiva Loka.** One should declare the greatness of Rudrākṣam to one’s own disciple; never to disclose its glories to one who is not a disciple nor a devotee of Rudrākṣam nor to him who is an illiterate brute. Be he a Bhakta or not a Bhakta, be be low or very low, if he holds Rudrākṣam then he is freed from all sins. No equal can be to the merit of him who holds the Rudrākṣams.

We can also understand the relative importance of the different faced beads from the [section below](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57382.html):

> **One faced Rudrākṣa seed is the Śiva Himself, made manifest and rendered vivid; even the sin iñcurred in killing a Brāhmaṇa is destroyed thereby.**

> Two faced or two headed Rudrākṣam is like the Deva and the Devī. **Two sorts of sins are destroyed thereby.**

> The three faced Rudrākṣam is like fire; the sin iñcurred in killing a woman is destroyed in a moment.

> The four faced Rudrākṣa seed is like Brahmā and removes the sin of killing persons.

> The five faced Rudrākṣam is verily an image of Rudra; **all sorts of sins, e.g., eating prohibited food, going to the ungoables, etc., are destroyed thereby.**

> The six faced Rudrākṣam is Kārtikeya. It is to be worn on the right hand. One becomes freed of the Brahmāhatyā sin. There is no manner of doubt in this.

> The seven faced Rudrākṣam is named Ananga. **Holding this frees one from the sin of stealing gold, etc., O Mahāsena!**

> The eight faced Rudrākṣa is Vināyaka. **Holding this frees one from the sin of holding an illicit contact with a woman of a bad family and with the wife of one’s Guru, etc., and other sins as well**. It enables one to acquire heaps of food, cotton, and gold; and in the end the Highest Place is attained.

> The fruit of holding the eight faced Rudrākṣa seed has been said. Now I will talk of the nine-faced Rudrākṣam. It is verily the Bhairava made manifest. On the left hand it should be worn. **By this, the people get both Bhoga (enjoyment) and Mokṣa (liberation) and they become powerful like Me and get themselves freed at once, without the least delay, of the sins iñcurred by committing thousands of abortions, hundreds of Brahmāhattyās (killing the Brāhmaṇas).**

> **Holding the ten-faced Rudrākṣa is verily wearing Janārdana,** the Deva of the Devas. The holding of which pacifies the evils caused by planets, Piśācas, Vetālas, Brahmā Rākṣasas, and Pannagas.

> The eleven-faced Rudrākṣam is like the Eleven Rudras. The fruits, the efficacy of which I now describe. Hear. **The fruits obtained through the performance of one thousand horse sacrifices, one hundred Vājapeya sacrifices, and making gifts of one hundred thousand cows are obtained thereby.**

> If one wears the twelve-headed Rudrākṣam on one’s ear, the Ādityas get satisfied. **The fruits of performing Gomedha and Aśvamedha sacrifices are obtained thereby. No fear comes from burned buffaloes, armed enemies and wolves and tigers and other murderous animals. Also the several diseases of the body never come to him. The holder of the twelve-faced Rudrākṣa seed feels always happy and he is the master of some kingdoms He becomes freed of the sins iñcurred in killing elephants, horses, deer, cats, snakes, mice, frogs, asses, foxes and various other animals.**

> O Child! The thirteen faced Rudrākṣam is very rare; if anybody gets it, he becomes like Kārti Keya and gets all desires fulfilled; and the eight siddhis are under his grasp. He learns how to make gold, silver and other metals; he attains all sorts of enjoyments. There is no manner of doubt in this. O Saḍānana!**If anybody holds the thirteen faced Rudrākṣam, he becomes freed from the sins iñcurred in killing mother, father and brothers.**

> O Son! **If one holds on one’s head the fourteen faced Rudrākṣam always, one becomes like Śiva. O Muni! What more shall I speak to you! The Devas pay their respects to one holding the fourteen faced Rudrākṣas and he in the end attains the Highest Goal, the state of Śiva. His body becomes verily the body of Śiva.**

It appears from the above references that the higher the number of faces, more is the spiritual value of the Rudraksha bead, and hence the one with fourteen faces would be the most powerful one based on this text instead of a single-faced one.